# How to fetch 2 api's in one component in React

Tags: reactjs

How to combine these 2 components CompanyProfile and CompanyProducts to get data through api or in other words access 2 api's in one page and export them as one component. Both are working but the api's are fetched separately as displayed in imports at the top

Below is the code....

```
    import React, { Component} from "react";
import CompanyProfile from './companyprofile';
import CompanyProducts from './companyproducts';


export class Search extends Component {
    render(){
              
        return(
            
            <div>

<div class="float-left w-50">
<CompanyProfile />
</div>

<div class="float-left w-50">
<CompanyProducts />
</div>
</div>

        
        
        )

    }
}
export default Search
```

Here is CompanyProfile example.....

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'


class CompanyProfile extends Component {

     constructor(){
          super();
          this.state={
               Company:[]
                              
          }
     }

     componentDidMount(){
          axios.get('http://localhost:3000/companyprofile.json').then(response =>{
               
               this.setState({Company:response.data});         

          }).catch(error=>{

          });
     } 
  
     render() {

          const contact = this.state.Company;
          const MyView = contact.map((contact,i)=>{

               return  <div>

  <div className="col-md-14 p-4 ml-2 float-left">
                                 
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Company Profile</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr><td><img class="float-left" src={contact.image} width="50" height="50" /></td>
  <td class="align-middle">{contact.name}</td></tr>
  <tr><td colspan="2 card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">{contact.description}</td></tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Value</td>
      <td>{contact.value}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Beta</td>
      <td>{contact.location}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>other data.....</td></tr>
  </tbody>
  
</table>
                           
     </div>
          </div>

          });

          return (
        
     <div>
               {MyView}
 
    </div>

          )
     }
}

export default CompanyProfile
```

Here is example of CompanyProduct......

```
    import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'


class CompanyProducts extends Component {

     constructor(){
          super();
          this.state={
               CompanyProducts:[]
                              
          }
     }

     componentDidMount(){
          axios.get('http://localhost:3000/companyProducts.json').then(response =>{
               
               this.setState({CompanyProducts:response.data});         

          }).catch(error=>{

          });
     } 
  
     render() {

          const contact = this.state.CompanyProducts;
          const MyView = contact.map((contact,i)=>{

               return  <div>

  <div className="col-md-14 p-4 ml-2 float-left">
                                 
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Company Product</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr><td><img class="float-left" src={contact.productphoto} width="50" height="50" /></td>
  <td class="align-middle">{contact.productname}</td></tr>
  <tr><td colspan="2 card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">{contact.productdescription}</td></tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Value</td>
      <td>{contact.productvalue}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Type</td>
      <td>{contact.type}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>other data.....</td></tr>
  </tbody>
  
</table>
                           
     </div>
          </div>

          });

          return (
        
     <div>
               {MyView}
 
    </div>

          )
     }
}

export default CompanyProducts
```

Comment: Props go from parent to child, not the other way. What problem are you trying to solve here? There's probably a better way to do it, that doesn't break the fundamental concept of "One Way Data Flow" in React.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply. I have updated the question and also added the 2 components. Basically I want to know how to fetch 2 api's in a single component instead of 2 different ones

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is call the api at a parent component, which is the Search Component, then pass the data down as props:

```
<Search> ----Call Api here
<CompanyProfile apiResult={apiResult}/>
<CompanyProducts apiResult={apiResult}/>
</Search>
```

Then in the CompanyProfile and CompanyProducts, you can access "apiResult" as a prop

Comment: I have asked a very specific question including full code. You answer does not explain anything of what I asked. If you can kindly provide the answer using the code that I provided.

Comment: @in.k This sure seems to give you the direction you asked for. SO isn't a code writing service. What part of this answer is unclear?

Comment: How does this give a direction to what I asked for. Google it and you can find this type of explanation or even better in hundreds. The specific question is how to combine the 2 components in one and export it. If you don't know, just read through. By upvoting such replies the genuine need for people to understand how a code works is overlooked.